# Shortened form of "the fact that she was alive"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Consider the following sentence:

> After she faked her death, she kept the fact that she was alive a secret from the rest of the world.

Here "the fact that she was alive" is a clear reference to her state of life, but I'd like to express this idea more concisely. It could be rephrased:

> After she faked her death, she kept her being alive a secret from the rest of the world.

Unfortunately, this is a bit awkward and could possibly become unclear without the starting clause ("After she faked her death").

Are there any other options?

Comment: Modern English unfortunately has evolved so that *the fact that ...* is an unavoidable ugly phrase. 200 years ago, it would have undoubtedly been phrased differently. See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+fact+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20fact%20that%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Would you be ok with a slight rewording to use a noun, such as "After she faked her death, she kept **her life** a secret from the rest of the world."?

Comment: I might be inclined to say "her survival".

Comment: @MarkBeadles Good suggestion. It does suffer from the same context problem as "her being alive", but it's a bit nicer.

Comment: @HotLicks, This is my favorite, and it's probably what I'll go with, but it may technically present a problem: Merriam Webster defines survival as "the act or fact of living or continuing longer than another person or thing", but what is the alternate person or thing in this case (I guess her hypothetical death?); the second definition of "the continuation of life or existence" seems like it works better, but that I feel like when I've seen that usage, it's more context-dependent than the words of the definition convey.

Comment: @Graham - When one of us old wheezers survives a heart attack it doesn't mean someone else didn't.

Comment: @HotLicks True; I'm probably over-analyzing to no benefit. I think it would be a good answer.

Comment: Her failure to die?

Comment: That she had faked her death was never discovered [until ...]

Comment: @HotLicks To me, the word "survival" implies that she was involved in an incident that she may not have survived. But faking her death need not involve any such incident.

Comment: Have you tried reading your sentence out loud? It is full of "d", "t", "k" and such. In particular, I would stay away from "fake" in the past tense.

Comment: @RustyCore I have not tried reading my sentence out loud prior to this moment; good suggestion! The consonants you mention don't really stand out for me. The sentence is a bit of a mouthful, perhaps for the reason you identify, but probably also because it's a bit long (cf. Sam's answer). I will admit I have not extensively studied phonetics. Is there a commonality between those particular consonants that makes them clash?

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, I meant to mention it 3 hours ago when I posted it, but I used your comment as the centerpiece for a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 4):

"The rest of the world" is a pretty tired cliche. Why not just rewrite as "She succeeded in faking her death" or "She successfully faked her own death"?

Comment: +1 I agree it's cliché. In my specific case, I have some specific contextual reasons for including the phrase "the rest of the world", but I think there are generally better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

[Hot Licks](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/70861/hot-licks)' suggestion happens to fit what I want, but it hasn't been posted as an answer, so I'll just post it myself:

> After she faked her death, she kept *her survival* a secret from the rest of the world.

---

It does come with a few caveats. While my comment fell short in identifying the a potential problem when using 'survival', [TrevorD](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/43980/trevord)'s comment successfully identified a commonly understood definition of 'survival':

> To me, the word 'survival' implies that she was involved in an incident that she may not have survived. But faking her death need not involve any such incident.

And as Sam notes in [their answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/493248/271182):

> "The rest of the world" is a pretty tired cliche.

Answer (score -2):

Her mortality
After she faked her death, she kept her mortality a secret from the rest of the world.

Herself 
After she faked her death, she kept herself a secret from the rest of the world.

Comment: 'Mortality' usually means 'ability to be killed'

Comment: “Mortality” can also mean *death*, and keeping her death a secret would seem to undermine the purpose of faking it. ;-)